# AppCompatActivity to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment, appcompatactivity

hi i want change this code to fragment . base of this code is AppCompatActivity and i need change but i cant .

my Mainactivity use fragment code to show all page

fragment = new FavoritesFragment();

if i use AppCompatActivity  or change FavoritesFragment page Mainactivity gets error

```
public class FavoritesFragment extends Fragment {


    public static TextView txt_status ;
    EditText et_amount , et_desc , et_email , et_mobile , et_mahsol ;
    Button btn_pay ;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        txt_status = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt_status);

        et_amount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_amount);
        et_desc = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_desc);
        et_email = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_email);
        et_mobile = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_mobile);
        et_mahsol = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_mahsol);

        btn_pay = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_pay);

        btn_pay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(et_amount.getText().toString().equals("") || Integer.parseInt(et_amount.getText().toString())<100){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"مبلغ وارد شده صحیح نمیباشد",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else if(et_desc.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"وارد کردن توضیحات الزامیست !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else if(et_email.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"وارد کردن hایمیل الزامیست !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else if(et_mobile.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"وارد کردن شماره همراه الزامیست !",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Payment.class);
                    intent.putExtra("Amount",et_amount.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("Description",et_desc.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("Email",et_email.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("Mobile",et_mobile.getText().toString());
                    intent.putExtra("Mahsol",et_mahsol.getText().toString());
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Obviously you just replaced AppCompatActivity with Fragment, which of course won't work. What's the error? Did you have a look at the Fragment documentation? https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Can you please post your error log. Please read up on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: anybody can change this code to fragment this is my uni project and i dont have any time .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fragments have different lifecycle callbacks, so you need to learn, you can not always find the ready code. You should look here for 5 minutes https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);

    txt_status = (TextView) rootView.findViewById((R.id.txt_status);

    et_amount = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.et_amount);
    et_desc = (EditText) rootView.findViewById((R.id.et_desc);
    et_email = (EditText) rootView.findViewById((R.id.et_email);
    et_mobile = (EditText) rootView.findViewById((R.id.et_mobile);
    et_mahsol = (EditText) rootView.findViewById((R.id.et_mahsol);

    btn_pay = (Button) rootView.findViewById((R.id.btn_pay);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    btn_pay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (et_amount.getText().toString().equals("") || Integer.parseInt(et_amount.getText().toString()) < 100) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "مبلغ وارد شده صحیح نمیباشد", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (et_desc.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "وارد کردن توضیحات الزامیست !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (et_email.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "وارد کردن hایمیل الزامیست !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else if (et_mobile.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "وارد کردن شماره همراه الزامیست !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), Payment.class);
                intent.putExtra("Amount", et_amount.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("Description", et_desc.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("Email", et_email.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("Mobile", et_mobile.getText().toString());
                intent.putExtra("Mahsol", et_mahsol.getText().toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

You can bind your views like this

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a new fragment, you just can't replace AppCompatActivity with Fragment. Fragment and Activity they are different and got different behavior.
better you take a look here
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: can you change this code to fragment this is my uni project and i dont have any time